# Xamarin PortSip Voip Client

Tags: xamarin

Has anyone tested the demo version from https://www.portsip.com/download, the Xamarin Client? If yes, works when xamarin client calls another client?
When I try to call on the Xamarin client, I receive the ECoreCallIdNotFound error and the call fails. Can anyone help me?
Thank's